# WSO2 API Manager: Suse kernel parameters

Tags: parameters, kernel, wso2, suse, futex

Are there any recommendations/requirements on `WSO2 API Manager` related to`kernel parameters` on `Suse 64bit`? Such as no-files, semaphores, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually recommend to increase the number of open files.

For more information, see http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Performance+Tuning

We also recommend Oracle/IBM JRE. See http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM150/Installation+Prerequisites

Other than that there are no specific requirements I can think of for now.

Also refer following for more details:
http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-fine-tune-wso2-api-manager.html

I hope this helps.